# Pattern selection Java Script Why Does it not work in Mozilla browser in chrome it just works fine?

Tags: javascript

Why does this does work in chrome and not in Mozilla Firefox?

```
<!-- This Jscript is for selecting only numbers -->
<script language="JavaScript">
    function onlyNumbers(evt) {
    var e = event || evt; // for trans-browser compatibility
    var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I don't see why this question should be down-voted, though it might be nice to do a bit more work before asking your question. For example, with a little elbow grease, you could have boiled the question down much - to "why is event defined in one browser and not another".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does this does work in chrome and not in Mozilla Firefox?

Because the (non-standard) global variable `event` doesn't exist in Firefox (but it does in Chrome). Trying to access a non-existing variable will result in a `ReferenceError`.

```js
console.log(iDontExist);
```

You should do

```
 var e = window.event || evt;
```

instead. Traditionally global variables are properties of the global object (`window` in browsers) but accessing non-existing properties returns `undefined` instead of throwing an error, so using `window.event` is a safer way to access a global variable that may not exist.

Comment: @CBroe `window.event` will evaluates to `undefined` if it is not defined. `event` will just give you an error right away because you are trying to access an undefined value.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, replace the code but same results   var e = window.event || evt;

Comment: @ArvindGK: What exactly is the result? What happens? Do you get an error? Do you not get the result you want?

Comment: I also use auto move to next field on filling the 7 digit required data :<!-- This Script for Auto move to next field -->
<script language="javascript">
 function myFunction(x, y) {
  if (y.length == x.maxLength) {
   var next = x.tabIndex;
   if (next < document.getElementById("compute1718").length) {
    document.getElementById("compute1718").elements[next].focus();
   }
  }
 }

</script>

Comment: the javascript should check for number in text field and accept only when numbers are entered , it works fine in chrome but not in FF

Comment: @ArvindGK: It works just fine for me in Firefox (https://jsfiddle.net/hh9aLxpe/). If it does not work you then there might be other issues in other parts of your code.